# NgXs selectSnapshot not working in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, ngxs

This describes pretty clearly how to write a unit test using NgXs
https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/unit-testing

So mimicking that I wrote a state with a SetLocale action:

```
export class SetLocale {
  static readonly type = '[Internationalization] SetLocale';
  constructor(public value: string) { }
}

export class InternationalizationStateModel {
  locale: string;
}

@State<InternationalizationStateModel>({
  name: 'internationalization',
  defaults: {
    locale: null
  }
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InternationalizationState {

  @Selector()
  static getLocale(state: InternationalizationStateModel): string {
    return state.locale;
  }

  @Action(SetLocale)
  setLocale(ctx: StateContext<InternationalizationStateModel>, { value }: SetLocale) {
    ctx.setState(
      patch({
        locale: value
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Nothing special there, and this works fine when used in the code. Next a unit test was added:

```
  let store: Store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([InternationalizationState])],
    });
    store = TestBed.inject(Store);
  });

  it('should process locale', () => {
    store.dispatch(new SetLocale('xx-XX'));
    const locale = store.selectSnapshot(s => s.locale);
    expect(locale).toBe('xx-XX');
  });
```

As far as I can see this is exactly how the guide suggests it, but this test fails with the fact the locale is undefined.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing the name of the state you are trying to snapshot:

Try: `store.selectSnapshot(s => s.internationalization.locale)`

or using your selector `store.selectSnapshot(InternationalizationState.getLocale)`